# ¿Es necesario crear una variable auxiliar para hacer un casting a un objeto de tipo Object?

Tags: java, cast, casting

Estaba sobrescribiendo el método `equals` de una clase y normalmente hago esto:

```
public boolean equals(Object otro) {
   Habitante aux = (Habitante) otro;
   return this.dni == aux.getDni();
}
```

Pero pensé que podía ahorrarme el `aux` y hacer:

```
public boolean equals(Object otro) {
    otro = (Habitante) otro;
    return this.dni == otro.getDni();
}
```

Sin embargo, da error de compilación y no entiendo por qué ya que esto sí que me lo deja hacer:

```
public static void aux(){
    double a = 2.0;
    a = (int)a;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál error obtienes?

Comment: Pues me dice que los métodos de otro no existen. Por ejemplo, todos los Habitantes tienen un DNI y un método getDNI(), pues si hago otro = (Habitante) otro y luego return this.dni == otro.getDNI() obtengo que no existe ningún método getDNI().

Comment: Ah, claro. Porque el tipo de la variable `otro` sigue siendo `Object`. No puedes cambiar el tipo de una variable pero si convertir una referencia a un tipo diferente.

Comment: @Mateo
>No puedes cambiar el tipo de una variable pero si convertir una referencia a un tipo diferente.
No entiendo muy bien esto, quiero decir,  'otro' es una variable referencia que apunta a un objeto de tipo Object y por lo tanto cuando hago un casting a 'otro' para que sea de tipo 'Habitante' lo que hago es cambiar el tipo de 'otro' y por lo tanto me debería dejar acceder a 'getDni()' ¿No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas una variable auxiliar. Puedes cambiar el tipo de parámetro:

```
public boolean equals(Habitante otro) {
    return this.dni == otro.getDni();
}
```

O hacer la conversión en la misma línea aunque quede feo:

```
public boolean equals(Object otro) {
    return this.dni == ((Habitante)otro).getDni();
}
```

Eso sí, si vas a dejar el parámetro de tipo `Object` no asumas que `otro` es del tipo correcto. Asegúrate de que es así primero y te evitarás errores.

```
public boolean equals(Object otro) {
    if (otro instanceof Habitante) {
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```